# QTP windows application recording using vb script

Tags: testing, qtp, hp-uft

I am recording a windows based application developed  using c#. Now, i want to perform automated test on this application using QTP. But, the problem is while capturing few objects using object spy, my test excute with below error:

```
Cannot identify the object "[ WinObject ]" (of class WinObject). Verify that this object's
  properties match an object currently displayed in your application.

Line (4): "Window("object class:=WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.329445b_r11_ad1","window 
    id:=1705523").Window("object class:=WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.329445b_r11_ad1","window 
    id:=2").WinObject("object class:=WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.329445b_r11_ad1","window 
    id:=1115822","x:=195","y:=140").DblClick 256,103". 

Please check attached snapshot for screen and object properties using object spy.
```

Here are screen captures:

[image: panel which is need to record]

[image: panel properties using object spy]

The problem I'm having while recording is that object spy unable to capture the particular area (i.e in this case the data shown on screen panel).

Answer (score 1):

It appears your issue is that you did not load the .NET add-in when launching QTP.  Without the add-in loaded, QTP sees windows as generic "WinObject" instead of a more framework-specific object.  For Windows Forms, you should see your window recognized as "SwfWindow".